# How to use the async await link button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise

Write a button to execute an async await function when it is pressed.

- The first time it is pressed, it will execute successfully and enter the success function.
- The second time it is pressed, it will fail and enter the falied function.

below is my trying i will continue updating.

My question now is although the number's boolean is false but the console.log output is still '成功'

***Not very good solution but i dit it.***

```
<button @click="get(number)">check</button>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      number: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    get(number) {
      this.number =! number;
      function success() {
        console.log('成功');
      }
      function failed() {
        console.log('失敗');
      }
      async function getter(number) {
        console.log(number);
        if (number == true) {
          let one = await success();
        } else if(number == false) {
          let two = await failed();
        }
      }
      getter(this.number)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as an "async await button" ... your code simply needs to use async await - good luck

Comment: @Bravo hello I knew no such things. i just don't know how to coding. i'm a beginner even i already read async class i dont know how to do. Want somebody help me. Thank you.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It works best when you show the code with your current attempt and explain the problem you have with it, so it could be fixed.

Comment: @Anita - stackoverflow isn't a code or homework writing service - that's what is wrong with your question - why is the `vuejs` tag present - hard to believe a complete learner is using vuejs without knowing how to write a single line of code

Comment: @Bravo I don't understand why but you make me feel so mean, I may not be a very good engineer but I'm trying very hard to learn, and I'm still trying to solve it now, and because I wrote it in .vue so I just added the tag.

Comment: I make you feel mean? you don't need to be mean - sorry if I offended you by telling you that you can't ask us to do your homework or write code for you - but that's just how this place works - if you feel mean, then that's your issue - but I see you've tried now - let me look at your code